# How track repetitive changes in a log file using python?

Tags: python, logging

I have an application that generates a log file. I have written an automation script in python to run the application. How do I correlate my python automation actions to the entries in log file? One approach I felt I could explore is based on Timestamps.

**Python script**

```
# script start time is 2019-01-29 15:59:59
enter_user_details()
login()
verify_login()
```

**Application logs file**

```
2019-01-29 15:59:53,546 [24] INFO  - StatusChanged: CONNECTING
2019-01-29 15:59:55,894 [25] INFO  - [LOGIN]: User login
2019-01-29 15:59:55,894 [25] INFO  - StatusChanged: DISCONNECTING
2019-01-29 15:59:59,738 [25] INFO  - [LOGIN]: User logged out
2019-01-29 15:59:59,738 [25] INFO  - StatusChanged: CONNECTING
2019-01-29 15:59:59,738 [1] INFO  - [LOGIN]: User login
2019-01-29 15:59:59,738 [1] INFO  - StatusChanged: DISCONNECTING
2019-01-29 15:59:59,748 [25] INFO - [LOGIN]: User logged out
2019-01-29 15:59:59,749 [1] INFO  - StatusChanged: CONNECTING
2019-01-29 15:59:59,751 [1] INFO  - [LOGIN]: User login
2019-01-29 15:59:59,755 [1] INFO  - Disconnecting...
```

Comment: Do you know that you're the only one here that knows how to parse these logs, right ? You know what they mean, we don't.

Comment: Actually I want to how to handle repetition in the logs..

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to handle repetition in the logs", because to every line seems unique.

Comment: How do I know which one was triggered by my script?.. The only way is to look at the timestamp to figure it out.. So I want suggestions if I could do it some other way..